# Neutral cohomology classes and restriction maps for $H^2$ in group cohomology

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\res{res}$
Let $G$ be a profinite group.
Let $A$ be a  finite $G$-group (a finite group on which $G$ acts continuously), not necessarily abelian,
with center $Z=Z(A)$.
We say that a second cohomology class $\xi\in H^2(G, Z)$ is *neutral* if
$$\xi\in\, {\rm im}\big[\delta\colon H^1(G,A/Z)\to H^2(G,Z)\big]. $$
If $A$ is abelian, then $\xi$ is neutral if and only if $\xi=0$.

Let $G_1,\dots,G_r\subset G$ be open subgroups of indices $n_1,\dots,n_r$, respectively,
where $\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_r)=1$.
We consider the restriction maps
$$\res_i\colon H^2(G, Z)\to H^2(G_i,Z).$$

> **Question.** For  $\xi\in H^2(G, Z)$,
> assume that the restrictions $\res_i(\xi)\in H^2(G_i,Z)$  are neutral for all $i=1,\dots, r$,
> where $\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_r)=1$.
> Does it follow that $\xi$ is neutral?

If $A$ is abelian, then the answer is **Yes**:
using the corestriction maps, from $\res_i(\xi)=0$ we deduce that $n_i\xi=0$ for each $i$,
whence $\xi=0$ because $\gcd(n_1,\dots,n_r)=1$.
In the general case, I would expect the answer **No**.